# Field missing from 'Quick Field Calculation Bar' in attribute table QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I work with PostgreSQL data, but when I want to calculate the data fields in the attribute table, I can't. I tried but some fields are hidden. How can I show all data fields for calculation?

image 1. All file of table

[image]

image 2. All data fields are display

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It's unclear what "Porgress" might be, but if you mean the open-source RDBMS, that's spelled "PostgreSQL".

Comment: Porgress = PostgreSQL